# RHEL9 make most of virtualisation features from RHEL7, how to upgrade to a modern OS?

Tags: centos, rhel, virtual-machine, kvm

I have a hypervisor that is installed on a CentOS 7.9.2009, with `qemu-kvm`.  I have some virtualised old VMs that I would like to migrate elsewhere on a more modern system.

I tried CentOS 9.0 and Rocky Linux 9.0.  Both systems seem to have lost a lot of virtualization features in the version upgrade.  They seem not to be compatible at all with my old system.  When I start the VM from the same XML, a lot of attached interfaces are not compatible anymore: raw IDE Disk, Spice interfaces, GXL screen, USB bridges, etc.

When I migrate, after removing most of the interfaces, I get the blue screen of death.  It does not seem this migration will be easy.  I have copied the old image and the old XML into the new hypervisor.

I do not need complex features, I only need a VM with disks as a file.

How can I migrate those VMs to a more modern system?  What should be my choice? Is it possible by copying the old VM images and XML?

Comment: Please show the exact error messages encountered. And if I am reading correctly, you have two hypervisors running right now. If so, I would create a new VM on the new hypervisor, and copy data files from old VM to new VM, using tools such as `rsync`.

Comment: @MaxPlankton There is two line of error for each single periferic that used to works on RHEL7

Comment: @MaxPlankton For example, bridged network is not working anymore....